# how to use akka.actor.Status.Failure to catch the exception

Tags: scala, akka

I have an actor which is responsible for MongoDB CRUD operations it may throw a `mongoException` i want to caught this exception in the calling code where i am using the ask pattern but i am still getting a TimeOutException which is not required in my case from the docs i have gone [over this link](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/actors.html#receive-timeout)

> Warning
>   To complete the with an exception you need to send an akka.actor.Status.Failure message to the sender. This is not done automatically when an actor throws an exception while processing a message.

I followed the code snippet given in the docs

here is my code

```
class test extends Actor {

def receive () {

case GetRecordLists=>
try {  
 //some operations here 
   sender ! resultList
}
catch {
  mongoEX:MongoException=>
  log.error("got mongodb exception",mongoex)
  sender ! akka.actor.Status.Failure(mongoEx)
  throw mongoEx

e:Exception=>
  log.error("got exception",e)
  sender ! akka.actor.Status.Failure(e)
  throw e
}

}

}


class MainClass extends App {

try {
     val future: Future[scala.collection.mutable.Set[String]] = ask(test, GetRecordLists).mapTo[scala.collection.mutable.Set[String]]
     val results = Await.result(future, timeout.duration)
    }
    catch  {
      case e:Exception=>log.error("got the exception in main class ",e)
      throw new Exception(e)
    }
}
```

here the expected behavior is to caught the `MongoException`
but i am getting

```
java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Futures timed out after [5 seconds]
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.ready(Promise.scala:219) ~[scala-library-2.11.1.jar:na]
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.result(Promise.scala:223) ~[scala-library-2.11.1.jar:na]
    at scala.concurrent.Await$$anonfun$result$1.apply(package.scala:111) ~[scala-library-2.11.1.jar:na]
    at scala.concurrent.BlockContext$DefaultBlockContext$.blockOn(BlockContext.scala:53) ~[scala-library-2.11.1.jar:na]
    at scala.concurrent.Await$.result(package.scala:111) ~[scala-library-2.11.1.jar:na]
    at MainClass(MainClass.scala:118) [xyz_2.11.jar:0.1.0-SNAPSHOT]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you do, looks correct. The only explanation for timeout error is that operation to mongo has not finished yet and `5 seconds` are not enough.

Please check a very simplified code that handles success and failure and timeout cases.

```
import akka.actor.{Actor, ActorSystem, Props}
import akka.actor.Status.Failure
import akka.util.Timeout
import akka.pattern.ask

import concurrent.duration._

class TestActor(body: () => String) extends Actor {
  override def receive: Receive = {
    case msg => try {
      sender() ! body()
    } catch {
      case ex: Throwable =>
        sender() ! Failure(ex)
    }
  }
}

object TestApp extends App {
  val system = ActorSystem("test")
  import system.dispatcher
  implicit val timeout: Timeout = 1.second
  val actorOk = system.actorOf(Props(new TestActor(() => "Hello")))
  val actorNok = system.actorOf(Props(new TestActor(() => sys.error("Boom"))))
  val actorTimeout = system.actorOf(Props(new TestActor(() => {Thread.sleep(3000); ""})))
  (actorOk ? "some message").mapTo[String].onComplete(println)
  (actorNok ? "some message").mapTo[String].onComplete(println)
  (actorTimeout ? "some message").mapTo[String].onComplete(println)
  Thread.sleep(2000)
  system.terminate()
}
```

Prints

```
Success(Hello)
Failure(java.lang.RuntimeException: Boom)
Failure(akka.pattern.AskTimeoutException: Ask timed out on [Actor[akka://test/user/$c#-765807830]] after [1000 ms]. Message of type [java.lang.String]. A typical reason for `AskTimeoutException` is that the recipient actor didn't send a reply.)
```